# A function $y=f(x)$ satisfies the condition $f'(x)\sin x+f(x)\cos x=1,f(x)$ being bounded when $x\to 0$.If $I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus

A function $y=f(x)$ satisfies the condition $f'(x)\sin x+f(x)\cos x=1,f(x)$ being bounded when $x\to 0$.If $I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(x)dx,$then

$(A)\frac{\pi}{2}<I<\frac{\pi^2}{4}\hspace{1cm}(B)\frac{\pi}{4}<I<\frac{\pi^2}{2}\hspace{1cm}(C)1<I<\frac{\pi}{2}\hspace{1cm}(D)0<I<1$

From the given equation $f'(x)\sin x+f(x)\cos x=1,f(x)$,i could not prove whether $f(x)$ is a monotonically increasing or monotonically decreasing function.Hence i could not find the upper and lower bounds of $I$.Please suggest me some method to solve it.

Comment: Hint: $f'(x)\sin x+f(x)\cos x =\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x)\sin x$

Answer (score 3):

As a follow-up to G-man's answer, notice that:
$$ I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{\sin x}\,dx = 2G, \tag{1}$$
with $G$ being [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant). $(1)$ follows from the Fourier sine series of the identity function:
$$\forall x\in(-\pi,\pi),\qquad  x = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\,\sin(nx)\tag{2} $$
from which:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} I = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(2nx)}{\sin(x)}\,dx &=&\; 2\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{2j-1}\\&=&\;4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\text{arctanh}(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\&=&\;2\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(y)}{1+y^2}\,dy\\&=&\;2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{-\log x}{1+x^2}\,dx\\&=&\;2\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-1)^2}\\&=&\,2G.\tag{3}\end{eqnarray*}$$
The last series representation clearly gives $\frac{16}{9}<I<2$, hence both $(A)$ and $(B)$ are correct.

As an alternative,
$$ I \geq \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2}}=\pi\cdot\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}\log(3)>\frac{\pi}{2}\tag{4}$$
and:
$$ I \leq \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{\frac{2}{\pi}\,x}\,dx = \frac{\pi^2}{4}.\tag{5}$$

Answer (score 2):

From the hint I gave in the comment you can say that the function is $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sin x}$. The maximum and minimum values that $f(x)$ attains in the given interval are $\pi/2$ and $1$ respectively. Now can you apply this to get upper and lower bounds for the integral?

**EDIT**: As Hagen has pointed out, the differential equation gives us the general form $f(x)=\dfrac{x+c}{\sin x}$. But the boundedness condition mandates that $c=0$, so that's that.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{x+C}{\sin x}$ follows from the differential equation, then $C=0$ from the boundedness condition

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes that's correct. I've only stated the important points in my answer, so that the OP can work out by themselves how to get them.

Comment: Its just that upon first reading "From the hint ..." one might get the impression that you forgot about the constant when in reality the constant is eliminated by the additional condition. A reader unaware of that might not even have noticed that there is a constant that needs eliminating ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen you're right. Sometimes I forget to think about the readers.